# Find value of unknown constant $k$ which is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Find a value of constant $k$ if possible, at which is continuous everywhere

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    kx^2, & x \leq 6 \\
    7x + k, &x > 6\end{cases}$$

Not sure how to do this problem. I think $kx^2$ and $7x +k$ are equal to each other when $x = 6$, but I’m not sure what to do after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set them equal to one another and plug in $x=6$.

Comment: I.e. solve $k\cdot6^2=7\cdot 6+k$